# Проблема с подключением к tcp серверу, который запущен на maui android

Tags: c#, сервер, esp32, tcplistener

Когда запускаю отладку через `Windows machine` в среде VS2022 esp32 адекватно  по локальному ip и определённому порту, который слушает само maui приложение, получает данные. Но как только я запускаю локально через эмулятор Android приложение, то тишина. Пытался определить через `tcpserver.server.localendpoint`, в таком случае показывает `0.0.0.0:`.
Может быть какая то внутренняя переадресация происходит и это нужно отражать в tcp клиенте при запросе?